# How to auto run a code multiple times on a site

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a javascript code which will automatically run itself multiple times on a site when i enter it in console . I have already tried and it works only once. Is there any way to automatically run it again and again  ?

Comment: [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)?

Comment: [setInterval(()=>{thecode},1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **setInterval** function.

Example:

```
function myFunction(){
  console.log('Success!');
}

setInterval(function(){
  myFunction();
}, 3000); //you can set the interval here.
```